# Pass a process to a subclass

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I would like to pass a process to a subclass so I may kill it but I can't figure out how to pass the process. I'm unsure how to store it so I can return it to the form and be able to call the subclass method to kill it. here are my classes

```
package my.mashformcnts;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


/**
 *
 * @author brett
 */
public class MashRocks {

    public static Process startThread(MashFormCnts mashFormCnts) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\Telegraph_Road.mp4", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\out.mp4");

        //Here is where i would like to name and store the Process


        final Process p = pb.start();
        // create a new thread to get progress from ffmpeg command , override  
        // it's run method, and start it!  
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getErrorStream());
                // Find duration  
                Pattern durPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=Duration: )[^,]*");
                String dur = sc.findWithinHorizon(durPattern, 0);
                if (dur == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse duration.");
                }
                String[] hms = dur.split(":");
                double totalSecs = Integer.parseInt(hms[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(hms[1]) * 60 + Double.parseDouble(hms[2]);
                System.out.println("Total duration: " + totalSecs + " seconds.");
                // Find time as long as possible.  
                Pattern timePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=time=)[\\d:.]*");
                String match;
                String[] matchSplit;
                //MashForm pgbar = new MashForm();
                while (null != (match = sc.findWithinHorizon(timePattern, 0))) {
                    matchSplit = match.split(":");
                    double progress = (Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[0]) * 3600 + Integer.parseInt(matchSplit[1]) * 60 + Double.parseDouble(matchSplit[2])) / totalSecs;
                    int prog = (int) (progress * 100);
                    mashFormCunts.setbar(prog);
                }
            }
        };
       t.start();
       return p;
    }
   public synchronized static void stop(Thread t) throws IOException{
           Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM ffmpeg.exe");  
            t = null;
          //t.interrupt();



   }
}
   class killMash extends MashRocks{
    public static void Kfpeg(Process p){

      p.destroyForcibly();
    }
}
```

So those are my classes. I'm very new.

Next there is the event Listener on the form, so when I click this I want to kill the ffmpeg proecess with the `Thread t`:

```
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Thread n = Thread.currentThread();
        System.out.print(n);
        try {
            //MashRocks.stop(n);
             //This isnt working but i think its closer
             killMash.Kfpeg(MashRocks.startThread(this)); 
//Not Sure what to do here
  //here is where i want to pass the process sorry for the typo
  killMash.kfpeg(p); 
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MashFormCunts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
```

Any help is awesome cheers

Comment: You have commented out t.interrupt(); in the MashRocks.stop(), which normally should stop your thread. What happens when you uncomment this line?

Comment: Sorry there was a typo there i have fixed it, nothing really happens as there isnt anything in the method. my issue is i cant passs kfpeg the process, I think thats the problem

Comment: Ok, the startThread returns the process you want to kill. I guess you store this result somewhere. You need to structure your code so you can access this value in the eventListner.

Comment: That's where I'm lost Nadir and i'm not sure i'm storing it or not

Comment: Find the place where you call MashRocks.startThread() and then check what is going on, is the return value assigned somewhere etc. I cannot really help more, because I dont see the whole project sources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to make everything static but if you need to one possibility would be to store the process as a class variable:

```
public class MashRocks {

    protected static Process process = null;

    public static Process startThread(MashFormCnts mashFormCnts) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\Telegraph_Road.mp4", "C:\\Users\\brett\\Documents\\out.mp4");

    final Process p = pb.start();
    MashRocks.process = p;
    ....
    }
}
```

Your stop method could be:

```
public synchronized static void stop() throws IOException{
    if(MashRocks.process != null)
    {
        MashRocks.process.destroy();
    }
}
```

And your sub class:

```
class KillMash extends MashRocks{
    public static void Kfpeg() throws IOException{
        KillMash.stop();
    }
}
```